# Joining 3 tables derived from count and group by statements

Tags: sql, count, group-by

What I am trying to do is summarize a bunch of data from one table (passbooking) into 4 columns. The first is simply a clientid, and the next three are numbers of bookings that meet certain criteria for each clientid.

The the third (OnDemandCancels) and fourth (DayCenterCancels) are subsets of the second (TotalCancels), and therefore some of the rows in the third and fourth columns ought to be zero.

For this reason I think I need to include the clientid for each of the columns when they are derived from the original table so that I can join them along clientid.

Here is as close as I have been able to get:

```
select
    pb.clientid,
    (select pb.clientid, count(pb.ldate) as TotalCancels 
        from passbooking as pb 
        where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
            and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
            and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
            group by pb.clientid) as tcxl,
    (select pb.clientid, count(pb.ldate) as OnDemandCancels 
        from passbooking as pb 
        where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
            and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
            and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
            and pb.bookingpurpose <> 'P-DayCt') 
            group by pb.clientid) as odcxl,
    (select pb.clientid, count(pb.ldate) as DayCenterCancels 
        from passbooking as pb 
        where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
            and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
            and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
            and pb.bookingpurpose = 'P-DayCt') 
            group by pb.clientid) as dccxl
from passbooking as pb
where pb.clientid = tcxl.clientid 
    and pb.clientid = odcxl.clientid 
    and pb.clientid = dccxl.clientid
```

This gives me an error "The multi-part identifier tcxl.clientid could not be bound".

I know that each of the subqueries function as I want them to on their own, my problem is just with figuring out how to join them properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Which database software are you using? MySQL, Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `JOIN`, use `case` expressions to do conditional counting instead:

```
select
    pb.clientid,
    count(pb.ldate) as TotalCancels,
    count(case when pb.bookingpurpose <> 'P-DayCt' then pb.ldate end) as OnDemandCancels,
    count(case when pb.bookingpurpose = 'P-DayCt' then pb.ldate end) as DayCenterCancels 
from passbooking as pb
where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
  and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
  and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
group by pb.clientid
```

**EDIT - as requested:**

"*what if I needed to now join this table to another table (I need to get the client names from a different table) Where do I add that join statement in here?*"

Simply `JOIN` the above query with the other table (called `ClientsTable` below):

```
select b.clientid, b.TotalCancels, b.OnDemandCancels, b.DayCenterCancels, c.clientname 
from
(
    select
        pb.clientid,
        count(pb.ldate) as TotalCancels,
        count(case when pb.bookingpurpose <> 'P-DayCt' then pb.ldate end) as OnDemandCancels,
        count(case when pb.bookingpurpose = 'P-DayCt' then pb.ldate end) as DayCenterCancels 
    from passbooking as pb
    where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
      and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
      and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
    group by pb.clientid
) b
JOIN ClientsTable c on b.clientid = c.clientid
```

Comment: This is perfect, and awesome to be honest. Thank you.

Now, what if I needed to now join this table to another table (I need to get the client names from a different table) Where do I add that join statement in here?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    pb.clientid
from passbooking as pb
inner join ( 
             ( select pb.clientid, count(pb.ldate) as TotalCancels 
               from passbooking as pb 
               where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
               and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
               and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
               group by pb.clientid)
               ) as tcxl
on pb.clientid = tcxl.clientid 
inner join (
             (select pb.clientid, count(pb.ldate) as OnDemandCancels 
              from passbooking as pb 
              where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
              and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
              and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
              and pb.bookingpurpose <> 'P-DayCt') 
              group by pb.clientid) 
            )as odcxl
on pb.clientid = odcxl.clientid 

inner join 
(
  (select pb.clientid, count(pb.ldate) as DayCenterCancels 
    from passbooking as pb 
    where pb.ldate >= 20170201 
    and pb.ldate <= 20170228 
    and (pb.schedulestatus = 430 or pb.schedulestatus = 420) 
    and pb.bookingpurpose = 'P-DayCt') 
    group by pb.clientid) 
)as dccxl
on pb.clientid = dccxl.clientid
```